# Redundanz oder Nachdruck?

Tags: adverb, style, redundancy

Bei Wendungen wie:

> Zusätzlich werden auch in Berlin und Hamburg neue Filialen eröffnet.

handelt es sich hier bei der gleichzeitigen Verwendung von **zusätzlich** und **auch** um eine Redundanz, da beides Hinzufügung wiedergibt? Oder eher nur eine Betonung, die keine Überflüssigkeit für den Satz darstellt?
Die Frage lässt sich auch auf andere kopulative Adverbien erweitern, etwa *außerdem*, *darüber hinaus*, *ferner*, *zudem* usw.

Comment: Bitte editiere deine Frage. Derzeit fragst du nach Meinungen, und Meinungsumfragen sind auf Stackexchange ausdrücklich unerwünscht. Du riskierst, dass deine Frage geschlossen wird. Bitte frage nach Fakten, also danach, wie so etwas nach wissenschaftlichen Kriterien zu klassifizieren ist, aber frage bitte nicht nach persönlichen Meinungen.

Comment: Ich würde sagen, nein, es ist keine komplette sprachliche Redundanz. Aber definitiv lässt es sich ohne den Kontext nicht sagen.

Comment: Der Satz könnte aus einer leicht aufgeblasenen Werbemeldung stammen, weil er sich ohne Bedeutungsverlust verkürzen lässt auf: *Auch in Berlin und Hamburg werden Filialen eröffnet*. (Man kann nur neue Filialen eröffnen, vorübergehend geschlossene lassen sich bestenfalls *wiedereröffnen*). In wiefern das *zusätzlich* eine Brücke zum vorigen Satz schlägt, lässt sich ohne Kontext nicht beurteilen.

Answer (score 4):

Ich vermute der Satz steht in einem Zusammenhang und die vorherigen Informationen bezogen sich auf andere Neueröffnungen in anderen Städten. Etwa so:

> Um der Unterversorgung der Bevölkerung in Großstädten entgegenzuwirken, haben wir in Frankfurt bereits zwei neue Verkaufsstellen eingerichtet. Zusätzlich werden auch in Berlin und Hamburg neue Filialen eröffnet.

Das "auch" bezieht sich dann auf die Städte, während das "zusätzlich" eher die Verstärkung der Bemühungen betonen soll:

> Seht her: Das tun wir dort und *zusätzlich machen* wir das *auch woanders*.

Also nein, nicht überflüssig und auch nicht redundant, sondern eher nachdrücklich.

Answer (score 0):

Man kann die Wörter betonen oder unbetont lassen. Nachdruck ergibt sich bei Betonung. Wenn das "auch" unbetont mitrutscht, klingt es recht redundant.

Es ist aber gar nicht so klar, dass man das "auch" weglassen sollte. Der Unterschied zwischen den beiden Wörtern ist, dass "zusätzlich" eine Aussage macht: "etwas kommt dazu (zu dem was wir schon hatten)". Das Wort "auch" macht keine Aussage, es ist eine Schattierung oder Abtönung, und es reagiert hier darauf, dass das "zusätzlich" schon da ist. Daher kommen häufig beide vor.

Ich denke, wenn man das "auch" weglässt und nur sagt: "zusätzlich werden in Berlin und Hamburg neue Filialen eröffnet", dann eignet sich das besonders, wenn "Berlin und Hamburg" völlig neue Information ist, oder wenn irgendwas mit Neueröffnungen überhaupt neue Information sind. Wenn aber von Berlin und Hamburg schon die Rede war, oder von der Existenz anderer Standorte schon die Rede war, dann würde ich das "auch" eher hinzufügen wollen. Das "auch" macht keine neue Aussage, sondern signalisiert im Hintergrund, dass es etwas vergleichbares schon im Text gab.